# Adding a method to an inherited inner class

Tags: scala

I made a lexer based on [Parsing M-Expressions in Scala with combinators](http://matt.might.net/articles/implementation-of-m-expression-parser-in-scala-combinators-without-stdlexical-stdtokenparsers/).

```
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.lexical._
import scala.util.parsing.combinator.token._

trait MyTokens extends Tokens {
  case class Id(chars: String) extends Token
  case class Num(chars: String) extends Token
}

class MyLexical extends Lexical with MyTokens {
  def whitespace = rep(whitespaceChar)
  def token: Parser[Token] = (
    rep1(letter) ^^ { case charList => Id(charList mkString "") }
  | rep1(digit)  ^^ { case charList => Num(charList mkString "") }
  )
}

object Main extends App {
  val lexical = new MyLexical
  val scanner = new lexical.Scanner("abc012def345")

  def tokenList(s: lexical.Scanner): List[lexical.Token] =
    if (s.atEnd) Nil
    else s.first :: tokenList(s.rest)
  println(tokenList(scanner))
}
```

It worked well resulting in `List(Id(abc), Num(012), Id(def), Num(345))`. However, the function `tokenList` should be a method of Scanner to call it as `scanner.tokenList`. In order to achieve it, it seems that the inner class `MyLexical.Scanner` should be overriden. Is it possible? If you can, how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can add a method to inner class, but you can use implicit conversion to achieve similar result. It would look like following:

```
object ScannerImplicits {
    implicit class BetterScanner(scanner: MyLexical.Scanner) {
       def tokenList(s: MyLexical.Scanner): List[MyLexical.Token] = {
         if (s.atEnd) Nil
         else s.first :: tokenList(s.rest)
       }
    }
}
```

Than you'll be able to write

```
import ScannerImplicits ._
new lexical.Scanner("abc012def345").tokenList
```

Comment: I got errors `not found: value MyLexical`, so I defined `BetterScanner` and `tokenList` with no arguments in `MyLexical` and did `import lexical._`, then it worked.